# ArgumentOutOfRangeException on Azure RemoteForwarder Plugin

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I currently have an Azure CloudService running and when I check the 'WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable', there is an error coming out every minute.

The details are as the following.

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    Length cannot be less than zero.
    Parameter name: lengthServer
stack trace: 
    at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpRemoteEndpointFinder.GetRemoteEndpoint(Socket clientSocket, Stream peekBuffer)Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.IRemoteEndpointFinder.GetRemoteEndpoint(Socket clientSocket, Stream peekBuffer)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RemoteForwardingService.ClientConnected(Object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.TcpSocketServer.OnClientConnected(ConnectionEventArgs e)
```

CloudService Config:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="*** omitted intentionally ***" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="*** omitted intentionally ***" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="2017-11-04T23:59:59.0000000+09:00" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" /> 
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Azure SDK Version:

```
v2.9.6
```

Any one have an idea what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have checked my `WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable` and I could find the similar logs as well. RemoteAccess and RemoteForwarder are used to support Remote Desktop access, for more details, you could follow this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/12/06/how-does-remote-desktop-works-in-windows-azure/).

Comment: Since I could remote to my web role and my site is always working. I assumed that this is an azure issue, and the error is thrown at `System.String.Substring` when `length` parameter is less than zero. Please try to add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role).

Comment: Yes, Bruce. I could also remote access to my webrole, so I am wondering why this kind of error occurs so often.
And thanks for the link to the blog, btw.
According to the article, my configurations doesn't seem to have any problems, so I think I would ask this to Microsoft.